# Is there a way to knitr and produce .rmd files using the external tools function of the StatET Eclipse plugin?

Tags: r, knitr, literate-programming, statet, r-markdown

I'm becoming a fan of reproducible analyses and of Sweave, Beamer and specially of the knitr package.

RStudio allows to Sweave and knit documents with just one click, but although RStudio is easy to install, it is quite unstable and does not have the maturity and flexibility of the StatET plugin from Eclipse. Most tutorials or listservs tend to refer back to the RStudio IDE when asking questions about knitr and RMarkdown, but there's little out there about how to install and turn Markdown files into `.Rmd` using the knitr package. Jeffrey Horner said when he announced the R markdown package that:

> "Markdown documents to HTML, created in collaboration with RStudio. It offers the complete R Markdown feature set available in their best-of-breed IDE, however useRs can integrate markdown into their own toolchain of choice."

The last sentence is what I have not been able to figure out. Elsewhere, I've seen suggested to manually knitr by using `library(knitr); knit('myfile.Rmd')`, however, when attempting to do this, I receive an error:

```
Warning in file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'My file.Rmd': No such file or directory
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
```

I was able to turn the `My file.md` file into html using:

```
library(markdown)
markdownToHTML(file = "C:/Dropbox/eclipse/8. CM/Myfile", output="C:/Dropbox/eclipse/8. CM/Myfile.html")
```

However, the R code is not run, and I suspect that I need to knit the `.Rmd` file first. Any help or directions about how to be able to knitr markdown files in StatET or somewhere else than Rstudio would be much appreciated.

I'm using R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22) on a Windows 7 Professional OS.
Eclipse Version: 3.8.0 and StatET 3.0.

Comment: for the first error you saw, it seems that you are not ware of the concept _working directory_ (type `getwd()` in R); the file `myfile.Rmd` must be under your current working directory; for the whole question, I hope StatET developers can pay attention to it; it really should not be too hard (see https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/252)

Comment: Hi Yihui, thanks for your package. I was aware of getwd(), but not of the fact that I had to manually change the file type to .Rmd before running in with knitr. The other issue was that my wd could not have spaces (i.e. 
"working directory"

Comment: (i.e. "\old projects\working directory") in the path. I hope this helps other users. Finally, I also hope StatET developers create a configuration to knit markdown in html.

Comment: Just to clarify, you can have spaces in the directory.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to use an **R snippet**:

1) create a stateET R project, with this file https://raw.github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/master/001-minimal.Rmd in it.

2) in Windows-> Preferences -> StatET -> Run/Debug -> R Code Snippets

click "Add...". to create a new snipped called **Rmd2html**.
content of the snippet:

```
file <- "${selected_resource_loc}"
if (!nzchar) stop('Select a file first')
library(knitr)
library(markdown)
library(tools)
md_file <- knit(file)
html_file <- paste(file_path_sans_ext(md_file), '.html', sep = '')
markdownToHTML(md_file, html_file)
```

click "OK", "OK".

3) back in your project, in the *Project Explorer* view, right click on the **minimal.Rmd** file,
and select "Run Code Snippet in R -> Rmd2html"

This should generate the minimal.html file.